# Use of selection in the code

Tags: java, android, android-listview

This code is one of the examples from Busy Coders Guide to Android. Chapter Getting Fancy With Lists, Section:A Dynamic Presentation.

The writer is trying to make a ListView using an alternate layout called rows. The name of the ImageView and TextView are icon and label.

However, I fail to understand what selection is used for. Also what is the use of the function onListItemClick with respect to this particular piece of code.

```
public class DynamicDemo extends ListActivity {
TextView selection;
private static final String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor","sit", "amet", "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel", "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis", "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante", "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue", "purus"};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setListAdapter(new IconicAdapter());
    selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
}
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v,
int position, long id) {

    selection.setText(items[position]);
}
class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    IconicAdapter() {
         super(DynamicDemo.this, R.layout.row, R.id.label, items);
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        if (items[position].length()>4) {
             icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
        }
        else {
             icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
        }
        return(row);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The onListItemClick() is the callback function when an item on the list is clicked.

The selection is a textview that is being set to the item that was clicked on.

Mainly showing how you can handle click events in list.